# How can I make google gauge read data from input tag which was created by a function above it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-visualization

I have created an Input tag from a function1() using `inputRowInputField = document.createElement('input')` and assigned an ID and Value using `inputRowInputField.id = "input_1"`, `inputRowInputField.value = 10`. I am trying to read value assigned above via google gauge defined in a function3() as below. Also i am creating `chart_div` as well from a function2()

```
function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['Test', Number(document.getElementById("input_1").value)]
        ]);
        var options = {
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
            height: 110,
            yellowFrom: 80,
            yellowTo: 90,
            greenFrom: 90,
            greenTo: 100,
            minorTicks: 2
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div');
        chart.draw(data, options);
```

I am calling the functions a below

```
function1()
function2()
google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['gauge']
    });
google.setOnLoadCallback(function3());
```

I get an error when function3() is called : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayToDataTable' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you're using an old version of google charts.
`jsapi` should no longer be used, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code).

remove...

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

add...

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the two statements in question...

now, for the issue...

`setOnLoadCallback` takes a reference to a function...

```
function3
```

not the result of a function...

```
function3()
```

change to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['gauge']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function3);
```

---

if you need to pass arguments to the callback function,
wrap it in another function...

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
  function3(arg1, arg2);
});
```

Comment: Actually function3 is also expecting some input variables. Am trying to figure out how can i pass variables. Could you please help me